# What is the ?: operator

Tags: objective-c, c, operators

In an example of Objective-C code I found this operator

```
self.itemViews[@(0)] ?: [self.dataSource slidingViewStack:self viewForItemAtIndex:0 reusingView:[self dequeueItemView]];
```

The code does compile under Apple LLVM 4.2.

The only thing I came across was in being a vector operator, but I don't think Objective-C, and for that matter C, has vector operators. So can someone please give reference and or documentation of this operator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`?:` is the C *conditional operator*.

```
a ? b : c
```

yields `b` value if `a` is different than `0` and `c` if `a` is equal to `0`.

A GNU extension ([Conditional with Omitted Operand](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html)) allows to use it with no second operand:

```
 x ? : y
```

is equivalent to

```
 x ? x : y
```

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't actually explain what happens. In this case, if `self.itemViews[@(0)]` is nil, the datasource is used to set a value.

Comment: But this is the only answer mentioning the fact that ?: is a GNU extension

Comment: Haha, overlooked that.

Answer (score 5):

Are you familiar with the [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)? 
Usually seen in the style:

```
test ? result_a : result_b;
```

All that has happened here is that the first branch has not been given so nothing will happen in the positive case. Similar to the following:

```
test ?: result_b;
```

Due to the way that C is evaluated, this will return `result_b` if test is untruthy, otherwise it will return `test`.

In the example that you have given -  if the view is missing, it falls back to checking the datasource to provide a replacement value.

Answer (score 3):

The above is called Ternary operator or conditional operator.

Syntax is,

```
     <condition>?<true_part>:<false_part>
```

Here if condition is true,  will be considered as value else  will be considered as value.

Please refer this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: What is the benefit of linking to the question mark character?

Comment: it is one line code with if then else feature. Saves lot of coding

Comment: i did not add 8 empty space before code. so it ended up in showing up ?: though the code is shown above. Sorry for not checking

Answer (score 1):

It is the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), as Objective-C is a superset of C you can use this operator.

Some [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#The_Ternary_Operator) on this.

> a = x ? : y;

The expression is equivalent to

> a = x ? x : y;

Answer (score 1):

It is the ? operator, called ternary operator, which is used in this way:

```
condition ? true-branch : false-branch;
```

When condition evaluates to true (non zero), the branch before the `:` is executed, otherwise the other branch is executed. This may even return a value:

```
value = condition ? true-branch : false-branch;
```

In your case the return value is ommited and the true-branch is empty (nothing to do). The return value of `condition` is returned then but not used in your example.

Equivalent of

```
if (!self.itemViews[@(0)]) 
  [self.dataSource slidingViewStack:self viewForItemAtIndex:0 reusingView:[self dequeueItemView]];
```

which is imho much better programming style.

Answer (score 1):

This operator is used in **Objective C** and this operator is used for conditional operator.Whether one statement will be run or while other it depends upon the logical term that is used and the input you are providing.